# In a tetrahedron, reflect each point over the line from an edge's midpoint through its center. Is it the tetrahedron itself?

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, euclidean-geometry, rotations, solid-geometry

Let $T$ be a regular tetrahedron, and $\ell$ a line from the midpoint of one edge $E_1$, through the center $C$, to the midpoint of another edge $E_2$.

How do I prove that the reflection of each point on the tetrahedron across this line $\ell$ is also on the tetrahedron? I can see this visually (especially when I rotate the model so as to look at $\ell$ head on), but don't know how to prove it.

My start is: $E_1$ and $E_2$ are each normal to $\ell$, and $\ell$ passes through their midpoints, so that any point on either of these edges clearly has its reflection on the tetrahedron.  The rest of the tetrahedron is generated by sliding $E_1$ across $\ell$ while rotating it to match $E_2$, so the reflection of each point along the way here is likewise on the tetrahedron.  While I believe this last sentence true, it itself needs to be proven.

---

## Update

Based on Blue and Dan Asimov's suggestions, I've developed the following proof, which I request verification of (hence the new `proof-verification` tag).

A regular tetrahedron is the polyhedron, unique up to similarity, with four vertices, each equidistant from all the others.  Therefore, any four mutually equidistant points form a regular tetrahedron.

[image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/26/Kepler%27s_tetrahedron_in_cube.png]

On a cube, choose an arbitrary vertex.  On each of this vertex's three faces, there is exactly one other vertex not on a common edge, thereby defining a set of four vertices.  Since any two of these four vertices are on a common face but not a common edge, they are all equidistant from each other ($\sqrt 2$ on a unit cube), and hence circumscribe a regular tetrahedron.  The cube's six faces will each have one of the tetrahedron's six edges coincident with one of the face's two diagonals.

Consequently, a line through the center of two opposite faces of the cube will also go through the midpoint of two opposite (i.e. non-adjacent) edges of the tetrahedron.  Rotating around this line by $90^\circ$ will map the cube to itself but switch the diagonal on each face to which the tetrahedron's edge is coincident.  Rotating around this line by another $90^\circ$ will switch this again, thereby restoring the tetrahedron to its original position.  This completes the proof.

Comment: Think of the tetrahedron sharing four of the cube's eight vertices, with edges along the diagonals of the cube's faces. The line in question joins the centers of two opposite cube faces. "Clearly", a half-turn about the line carries the cube to itself ... and the tetrahedron comes along for the ride.

Comment: @Blue I found [Kepler's diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Kepler%27s_tetrahedron_in_cube.png) which illustrates your point.  But is this a proof or a visualization? To me, it seems a great way to visualize it, but until we prove that the tetrahedron inscribes that way, it's no more than that.

Comment: Take four of the cube's vertices, no two diametrically opposed. Join them with edges that comprise six cube-diagonals; those edges, all being equal, form four equilateral-triangle faces. Voila! An inscribed regular tetrahedron. ... If you like, you can prove whatever you need (about the inscribed-ness, or your symmetry) using the vertex coords $(1,1,1)$, $(-1,1,1)$, $(1,-1,1)$, $(1,1,-1)$. (The remaining $(\pm1,\pm1,\pm1)$s complete the cube ... and determine a second inscribed tet!) Your line is a coord axis; the half-turn's effect on coords is easily described. ... Good luck! :)

Comment: "until we prove that the tetrahedron inscribes that way":  All that is needed is to show that the six edges have equal lengths. So pick convenient coordinates for the vertices and calculate. You could even just show the squared lengths to be equal.

Comment: @Blue That's very helpful.  Please see revised post with proof.

Comment: @DanAsimov Thank you - looking at a tetrahedron as "four mutually equidistant points" did it.  Please see revised post with proof.